# bashが変数を読み込みません

Tags: bash

bashが`~/.profile`や`~/.bash_profile`のファイルの変数を読み込みません。
例えば`.bash_profile`に

```
export x=100
```

として

```
echo $x
```

としてもxの値が出力されません。
`/etc/profile`の設定は

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

のようになっています。

Comment: 設定ファイルを変更した後、bashを起動し直すとどうなりますか？ / もしくは直接`source ~/.bash_profile`で読み込んだ場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: `~/.bash_profile`に書き込む必要がある場合は解決策にはなりませんが,もし`~/.bashrc`に書き込んでも良いならばそちらに書き込んでみてはどうでしょうか.`~/.bash_profile`はログイン時にしか読み込まれませんので,新しくbashを起動するなどしたら読み込まれない可能性があります.後もしかしたら`~/.bash_profile`がログイン時にしか読み込まれないのが原因かもしれないので`.bash_profile`に書き込んだ後コンピュータを再起動したら読み込まれるかおしれません.

Answer (score 2):

デフォルトでは`~/.profile`や`~/.bash_profile`はログインシェルが起動するときに読まれます。
`bash -l`や`bash --login`のようにログインシェルとして起動すると希望通りに動作すると思います。

Answer (score 1):

当時`sh`は起動時に`.profile`を使用していました。

現在`bash`は最初に`.bash_profile`をロードしようとします。 しかし、それが存在しない場合`.profile`をロードします

`bash`が`sh`として起動される場合（たとえば、`/bin/sh`は`/bin/bash`へのリンク）、または`--posix`フラグで起動される場合、`sh`をエミュレートしようとし、`.profile`

そのため、`〜/.bash_profile`を直接使用してみてください

Comment: 質問内容を見ると、 `~/.bash_profile` に記載しても読み込まれていないように見えます。

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bash_profile`に記述した環境変数は次の操作で有効になります。

- ログインしなおす
- `su -`を実行する　※`su`では有効になりません
- `source ~/.bash_profile`または`. ~/.bash_profile`を実行する

なお、`~/.bashrc`に記述すればbashが起動されるたびに実行されます。

伽語蓮弥さんの回答のとおり、`~/.profile`や`~/.bash_profile`はログイン時にだけ読み込まれるようです。
ログイン後のbashは`~/.bashrc`をカレントシェルで実行します。
※straceでbashを起動して確認した結果です。

私の環境の`~/.bashrc`は`/etc/bashrc`をカレントシェルで実行しています。※.bashrcはデフォルトのままです。

試した環境は次のとおりです。
CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core)
GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)